# I do not understand What is wrong in this code?

Tags: c

I have a problem in this code. When I wrote the coordinates like (1,1) and (1,20) it gives me wrong answer like -1.IND00.What is wrong with this code here is my problem :

b.  Write a C program that allows input of any two points in the Cartesian coordinates system and computes and displays the distance between them. To calculate the distance, write a function named distanceBetweenTwoPoints or DBTwoPoints that accept the floating point coordinates of two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) and compute the distance d between these two points to be returned to the calling function. (10 points) Hint: The distance between two points is defined as

```
float distance(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){
float result;
result=sqrt((pow((x2-x1),2))-(pow((y2-y1),2)));
return result;

}
int main () {

int x1,y1,x2,y2;

printf("enter your x1,y1");
scanf("%d%d",&x1,&y1);
printf("enter your x2,y2");
scanf("%d%d",&x2,&y2);

printf("result is %f",distance(x1,y1,x2,y2));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is why you must check the return value of `scanf`: it tells you how many arguments were read successfully.

Comment: It should be `sqrt(pow(a,2) + pow(b,2))`. `+` instead of `-`.

Comment: One basic debugging technique is to print the input values to ensure that the computer sees what you think it should be seeing.  Either in the debugger or with `printf()` statements.  Did you include `<math.h>`?

Comment: Your assignment requires floating point coordinates and stipulates the function name.  You seem to be ignoring these details.

Comment: Thank you all of you very very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is due to the subtraction in the cartesian computation.

It should be an addition (Think of it like if it was a Pythagorean Theorem) :

```
result=sqrt((pow((x2-x1),2))+(pow((y2-y1),2)));
```

Comment: Thanks all very very much